# Is there any history of merges made locally against uncommitted changes with TFS?

Tags: tfs

Using TFS and Visual Studio, one of my colleagues lost some changes when doing a merge (pulling latest version from the server onto a set of uncommitted changes on his local machine).  The merged version was then subsequently committed to the server.

Does anybody know if there is a history of the merges that happen on a local machine for these uncommitted changes (in an attempt to retrieve the lost code)?

Answer (score 6):

Uncommitted is uncommitted. It's not stored in source control. It's gone.

The only possibility would be if your colleague had a shelveset containing the changes, but that would be an action that would have to have been taken manually.

Comment: No, I'm aware of that, just curious if there was some sort of local 'recycle bin' for files prior to merge.  Wish we were using GIT...

Comment: Git wouldn't stop you from overwriting uncommitted changes, either.

Comment: Nope, I know, but much easier to commit regularly to your local repository without affecting anybody else.